# generate subscript in controller and pass to view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

In controller, I can pass string to view.

How can I pass string with subscript?

In html its easy, just use a `<sub>` tag.

I tried 3 times to pass this subscript to view but failed.

1. If I pass `<sub>` inside the string, it will display  `I<sub>tag</sub>` instead of I<sub>tag</sub>.
2. If I use `string1="string"+<sub>+"tag"+</sub>` ,and pass
   `string1`, The controller will give error!
3. Last, I tried directly to copy subscript string inside the page, I
   also got an error that it can't get displayed.

How can I pass subscript string to view? I got to loop different conditions so I cant each use `<sub>` tag, I need pass from controller.

**Edit:**

I tried this code in controller

```
  @valuedisplay=@value.to_s + " m/s<sup>2</sup>".html_safe
```

As suggest solution ,and I get:

[image: what shows up in web page]

Just as what I said in 1st try,display the `<sup>` instead of m<sup>2</sup>.

If I do it in view,I have many different types of data ,I need add checking data type code in view according to different types,its doable but will make the view  messy, I felt there should be a neat way to settle it in controller?

Answer (score 1):

You need to safely render the HTML in your view, and for this purpose, you need to call `html_safe` function on your string:

```
@str = "I<sub>tag</sub>".html_safe
```

And, now when you pass this `@str` to your view, it will render the `@str` as expected.

In view:

```
<%= @str %>
```

**Caution:**

It would be a very bad practice to do so. `<sub>ag</sub>` belongs to view, so it should be in view. You can do something like following:

In controller:

```
@str = "tag"
```

And in view:

```
I<sub><%= @str %></sub>
<%# or %>
<%= "I<sub>#{@str}</sub>" %>
```

Comment: I tried but it displayed I<sub>tag</sub> with the sub tag displayed...I<sub>tag</sub> ,copy past with subscript  "I₄".html_safe also give error:"We're sorry, but something went wrong." ..

Comment: How is it possible? I checked it out myself. Write `@str = "I<sub>tag</sub>".html_safe` and in your view, `<%= @str %>`, it should render it correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your effort but its not working as I expected,I have updated the out come of ur suggest code in question under Edit.